# vbscript to check if a process is running, if its not then copy a file from network

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VB scripting and need help on a program to do the following, Can someone please help me out. It would be great if this whole program can be embedded into one vbscript.

Write a script to check

1. if a process is running or not( example notepad++.exe),
2. if its running then dont do anything.
3. If the process is not running, check if a directory is present or not under C:\Program Files(x86)
4. Say if the directory is not there then copy the .exe file from a network shared location onto a local drive and
5. then perform the command line installation in silent mode.(example> notepad++.exe -ms)

Comment: First, welcome to StackOverflow. Second, read the FAQ to know what kind of and how to ask questions.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this example. You need to put an `if` check and compare with `objItem.Name = "notepad.exe"` and do whatever you wish to do:

```
   sComputerName = "."
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
   sQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"
   Set objItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(sQuery)
   'iterate all item(s)
   For Each objItem In objItems
       WScript.Echo "Process [Name:" & objItem.Name & "]"
   Next
```

Answer (score 6):

Also note you can use `WHERE` statement in query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '%notepad%'
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can find names of columns for query:

Comment: The link was absolutely pertinent.

Comment: @alfadog67: I wish it also had a property for the user name under which the process is running. It has `SessionID` but that changes depending on which user logs in first. So it's kinda useless.

Comment: @c00000fd, in Rohtash example below, add this after the "For Each": ret = objItem.getUser(uName, uDomain) - uName will be the username who created the process, and uDomain will contain the domain. The link has this listed under "Methods". I agree, useless if you don't read it.

Comment: It would only matter who the user is if you want to install a version for that user only and not everyone, right?

Comment: The WHERE technique should be much faster as there are hundred(s) of process running.