# Running PuTTY -m in background (no window wanted)

Tags: windows, background-process, putty

I am running PuTTY from a Perl script using the system command (Windows 7).  I use the `-m` command line option and it works great, but I do not want a window popping up. It's a short lived session, so it is annoying having the window open up for a second to make the connection and then close.

I searched *"windows background"* *"putty background"* and many other variations. I got close but no cigar.  The thread "Run putty jobs...MATLAB"  Was oh so close, but I was already doing that.

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable by using a VB script to call `plink.exe -batch -load [SessionName]`.

Assume the command line you need is like this:

```
plink.exe -batch -load SSHSession
```

Now you could write a VB script named `launchPlink.vbs` to check for a running instance of `plink.exe` and that particular session name. If no process was found then load `plink.exe` in a hidden window:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
sQuery = "SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='plink.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%-load SSHSession'"
Set objItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(sQuery)
If objItems.count = 0 Then
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    intReturn = objShell.Run("plink.exe -batch -load SSHSession", 0, False)
End If
```

To call the script just use the following line:

```
wscript.exe launchPlink.vbs
```

This method can also be used with task scheduler to check and restart the connection if something goes wrong.

Look at the following links for more details:

- [Ways To Run Batch Files Silently And Hide The Console Window](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hidden-start-runs-batch-files-silently-without-flickering-console/)
- [VBscript to check if a process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261317/vbscript-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-if-its-not-then-copy-a-file-from-netw)
- [Run Method (WindowsScript Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
- [Win32_Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make PuTTY not show its window. See [PuTTY wish no-terminal-window](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/no-terminal-window.html).

Though you may use Plink instead. The Plink is a tool from PuTTY suite, with the same functionality and command-line arguments as PuTTY (including the `-m`). But contrary to PuTTY, it is a console application. So when you run it from your Perl script, it will inherit the Perl console window. It won't open its own.

See [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

---

Note that the Plink supports specifying a command on its command line, so you can actually avoid using a temporary file for the `-m` switch:

```
plink.exe -ssh user@example.com "command"
```